# $Mat_{ \infty,n }(\mathbb C)$ of max rank is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, zariski-topology

We want to show that for a given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the set of all the $\infty\times n$ matrices $Mat_{\infty,n}(\mathbb{C})$ of max rank $n$ form a contractible space.

This set is obtained by taking the limit on $k \geq n$ in $Mat_{k,n}(\mathbb{C})$ with max rank $n$, being all $Mat_{j,n}(\mathbb{C}) \subset Mat_{j+1,n}(\mathbb{C})$ by adding a new raw of zeros. Our space is endowed with the Zarisky topology, given by induction on the Zarisky topology of the $Mat_{k,n}(\mathbb{C})$'s .

I don't think this is a CW-complex so I don't know which strategies to use. If we remove the $\infty$ the result is no more true, really similar to $S^n$ and $S^{\infty}$.

Thanks!

Comment: How is the Zariski topology defined?

Comment: @san I restated the whole text! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you say the result isn't true if you change $\infty$ to some finite $k$.  It wouldn't be true for the Euclidean topology but the Zariski topology is _very_ different...

Comment: In particular, my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2294516/86856 actually shows that $Mat_{k,n}(\mathbb{C})$ is contractible in the Zariski topology for any $k\geq n$.  I haven't worked out the details yet but I think it should be easy to extend the argument to the infinite case.

Comment: Can you be precise about _exactly_ what your space $Mat_{\infty,n}(\mathbb{C})$ is, though?  When you say $\infty\times n$ matrices, do you mean that all but finitely many entries in the matrices must be $0$?  And you are saying that a subset $U\subseteq Mat_{\infty,n}(\mathbb{C})$ is open iff $U\cap Mat_{k,n}(\mathbb{C})$ is open in the Zariski topology on $Mat_{k,n}(\mathbb{C})$ for all finite $k$?

Comment: @EricWofsey We are trying to construct the universal principle (equivariant) bundle for $GL_n(\mathbb C)$. This is the case iff $E \to B$ is a principal equivariant bundle for $GL_n$ and $E$ is contractible. Since $Mat_{k,n}^{max} \to Gr(n,k)$ is a principle $GL_n$-equivariant bundle (Gr is the Grassmaniann, everything with the Zarisky topology). I don't think $Mat_{k,n}^{max}$ is contractible or the exercise would be useless. Now take the limit of the inclusions $Mat_{k,n}^{max} \to Mat_{k+1,n}^{max}$ and $Gr(n,k) \to Gr(n,k+1)$ and their bundle maps

Comment: @EricWofsey , then $Mat_{\infty,n}^{max} \to Gr(n, \infty)$ is universal principle equivariant bundle cause $Mat_{\infty,n}^{max}$ is contractible.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want the Zariski topology?  Pretty much no one ever does homotopy theory using the Zariski topology.

Comment: In particular, if you actually seriously want to understand vector bundles or something like that, you would not be using the Zariski topology.  The question you have written has nothing to do with the geometry of vector bundles and instead is an exercise in pathological pointset topology.

Comment: @EricWofsey I would say that these matrixes have finitely many not-0 entries, and all of them have max rank. I don't know how to describe open sets. I guess there is Zarisky topology cause $Gr(n,k)$ needs it.

Comment: @EricWofsey here next to the definition of $Mat_{k,n}^{max}$ it is explicitally stated "with Zarisky topology". I don't know if we mean that $Mat_{\infty,n}^{max}$ is contractible with the Euclidean topology, if it makes sense.