# $\mathbb C^{\infty}\setminus\{0\}$ retracts on $S^{\infty}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

We want to show that $\mathbb C^{\infty}\setminus\{0\}$ retracts on $S^{\infty}$.

$C^{\infty}\setminus\{0\}$ should be the same as $\mathbb R^{\infty}\setminus\{0\}$. Maybe the retraction could be $(1-t)x + t \frac{x}{|x|}$?

Comment: With which topology do you view $\mathbb C^\infty$?

Comment: @barto the one given by limit induction on $\mathbb C^n / 0$, which has the one used for $\mathbb C^n /0 \subset \mathbb P^n C$.

Comment: I think you need to specify *which* $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ you mean. If it has a norm, then your retraction works. If it just has the product topology, then the usual norm is not continuous, so your retraction won't work. But then it's not clear how you even define $S^\infty$, etc. I think actual definitions for your spaces would make this question easier to parse (and answer).

Comment: @SteveD consider $\mathbb C^{n} / \{0\}$ as an euclidean space, and it's limit for $n \to \infty$. Then consider the $S^{\infty}$ of radius $1$ it contains.

Comment: @SteveD I want to show that $\mathbb C^{\infty} / \{0\}$ is contractible, that's why I retract it to the sphere and then use that it is contractible.

Comment: Oh, that is much easier! you can do a straight-line homotopy 
$$ (1-t)(x_1,x_2,\ldots) + t(0, x_1, x_2,\ldots)$$
and then another straight-line homotopy 
$$ (1-t)(0, y_1, y_2, \ldots) + t(1, 0, 0, \ldots) $$
the product is a deformation retraction to a point.

Comment: @SteveD Wow! Nice moves!

Comment: @SteveD maybe you have some clues on how to perform another contraction? It also has 200 points bounty but no one seems to know the answer! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876889/mat-infty-n-mathbb-c-of-max-rank-is-contractible

Comment: You have to define properly what $\mathbb  C^\infty$ is. In its present  form it is impossible to give an answer.