# Fundamental group of uncountable space with cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

So it is easy to show that such a space is path connected (assuming CH, injective maps $f:I \rightarrow X$ are continuous) but I'm not sure how to start computing the fundamental group. Will it depend on the cardinality?

Thank you

Comment: Well, assuming if your space has cardinality $\geq \mathfrak{c}$ you can do the same argument and see that any injective map $f: I^2\to X$ will be continuous, so the fundamental group is trivial.

Comment: What happens if we already have a bijection $I \rightarrow X$? Can we construct an injection $I^2 \rightarrow X$?

Comment: NVM, it isn't a loop then

Comment: I might have been a bit quick indeed, but note that "injectivity" is a much stronger condition than continuity; it suffices that every point has a finite number of antecedents, and this will get you closer to an actual solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming $|X|\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$, then $X$ is contractible so its fundamental group is trivial.  To prove this, let $f:X\times(0,1)\to X$ be an injection (here we use the fact that $|X|\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$).  Define $H:X\times[0,1]\to X$ by $H(x,0)=x$, $H(x,1)=x_0$ for some fixed point $x_0\in X$, and $H(x,t)=f(x,t)$ if $t\in (0,1)$.

I claim $H$ is continuous, and thus a contraction of $X$.  To show this, it suffices to show $H^{-1}(\{x\})$ is closed for each $x\in X$.  If $x\neq x_0$, then $H^{-1}(\{x\})=\{(x,0)\}\cup f^{-1}(\{x\})$ which is a finite set and hence closed.  If $x=x_0$, then we have $H^{-1}(\{x_\})=\{(x_0,0)\}\cup f^{-1}(\{x_0\})\cup X\times\{1\}$ which is a union of finite sets and the closed set $X\times\{1\}$ and thus also closed.  Thus $H$ is continuous, and $X$ is contractible.

See [What is the homotopy type of the affine space in the Zariski topology..?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514578/what-is-the-homotopy-type-of-the-affine-space-in-the-zariski-topology) for an interesting generalization of this argument to some related spaces that arise naturally in algebraic geometry (though their fundmental groups do not arise naturally!).

---

If you don't assume $|X|\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ (or CH), then I don't know what can be said in general.  It is consistent for $X$ to be totally path-disconnected if $|X|<2^{\aleph_0}$ (see https://mathoverflow.net/a/48991/75) and so the fundamental group with any basepoint will still be trivial.  But if $|X|<2^{\aleph_0}$ and $X$ is not totally path-disconnected, I don't know what can be said about its fundamental group.